# Stream using behavior

Tags: c#, file-io, stream

I got simple code, which basically copies file from one dir to another.

```
string fileName = "kur.csv";
var path = @"D:\" + fileName;
Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
using Stream s = File.Create(path); // remove "using" from this line
stream.CopyTo(s);
```

But if I remove "using" (from 4th line start) - code doesn't work on *.csv or *.txt files. But works on *.jpg, *.docx files.

Why it works on some and why it doesn't work on others?

Comment: Maybe it's because the text files can be written by `Stream` after opening. But non-text files must be opened using something else in .Net.

Comment: Well, problem is that on *.txt files it is NOT working. It DO work even on *.xlsx files. I though there is something with file size. But no. Larger files are copied. Smaller files - not. I am really confused.

Comment: "Why incorrect code sometimes produce expected results" is not a very useful question. Have `using` for both source and destination streams and enjoy correct working code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's a point. Learn from mistakes. But I must understand why mistake works too.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to write a method that copies a file, I'd do something like this:

```
static void CopyFile(string fileName)
{
    var scourceFilePath = Path.Combine(@"D:", fileName);
    var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(@"D:", "destination", fileName);

    File.Copy(scourceFilePath, destinationFilePath);
}
```

This works for all filetypes. You could also check if the directory exists (`Directory.Exists(directoryPath)`) before referencing it which prevents the program from crashing if the directory does in fact not exist.

I use `Path.Combine` since by using it I don't have to keep track of the backslashes used.

Every method I mentioned and used is contained in the System.IO namespace.

I hope, that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know there are many more ways to achieve task. I am not asking how to do it. I am asking what is happening behind scenes with my code